# MySQL longer than text size, shorter than mediumtext size

Tags: mysql, text, types, size

I am using MySQL to store web source code. The problem is that "How can I store size of source code which is longer than 64KB?" If I use TEXT data type, it truncates source code. But If I use MEDIUMTEXT data type, it would be a stunt, because MEDIUMTEXT size is 16MB! Do I have to make useless space that takes 15MB, whenever I store size of 1MB? please tell me. What should I do? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL `BLOB` and `TEXT` types are stored separately from the main table, and the storage required is equal to the length of the string plus a few bytes to set the length. Whatever type you use, the storage space used will only be roughly the size of the string.

In your particular case, `MEDIUMTEXT` will be fine - don't worry about large amounts of wasted space.

You can find more info in the [MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html)